# Shared pointer on x86 and ARM

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, arm

In a shared library (.so) I define a std::shared_ptr to a class object which is returned to the caller accross the library boundary to the main routine which is a Qt5.4 project. There the pointer is used in a if statement. As the bool operation is the last owner of the shared pointer it is deleted after finishing this operation and the destructor is called.

.so file (an Autotools-project):

```
#define STD_SHARED_PTR std::shared_ptr
#define STD_WEAK_PTR std::weak_ptr

typedef STD_SHARED_PTR<RenderingControl> RDCH;
typedef STD_WEAK_PTR<RenderingControl> WEAK;

class MediaRenderer {
    public:
        RDCH rdc();
}

class RenderingControl {
    public:
        RenderingControl();
        virtual ~RenderingControl();
}

RenderingControl::RenderingControl() {
    ...
}

RendeneringControl::~RenderingControl() {
    cerr << "Destructor called" << endl;
}

RDCH MediaRenderer::rdc() {

    RDCH rdcl = RDCH(new RenderingControl());
    long foo = rdcl.use_count();

    WEAK rdc = rdcl; 
    return rdcl;
}
```

.cpp (a Qt5.4 project):

```
typedef STD_SHARED_PTR<RenderingControl> MRDH;

MRDH renderer = MRDH(new MediaRenderer());

if (renderer->rdc()) {
    ...
    return;
}
```

Everything works fine on a x86 machine compiled with either Qt4.8 or Qt5.4. The destructor is called after finishing the if statement. Cross compiled for an ARM (Raspberry Pi 2) using Qt5.4, however, the destructor is not called. If I additionally add use_count() for debugging, it yields 1 in both the .so and the .cpp file on the x86, but 1 in the .so and 0 in the .cpp for the ARM.

If I compile on ARM using Qt4.8 everything is fine on ARM, too. But why does it not work on ARM using Qt5.4?

Thank you!

Comment: You did a good job cutting down the code shown to relevant bits. Now, you've been *so* close to actually show *compilable* code... because I have my doubts that a `use_count()` of 1 equals a called destructor while a `use_count()` of 0 doesn't...

Comment: use_count() was only added for debugging. I know that it does not give corect values in evry case

Comment: Yes, but the results are a bit contradictory, and generally we prefer code samples that we can run through our compilers to get the same result as you are describing in your question (to rule out any hidden issues). I don't see why the code you've shown should behave differently, so chances are the differences are in the code you *didn't* show...

Comment: What does Qt have to do with all of this? It defines `QSharedPtr`, not `std::shared_ptr`. I suspect the real cause is that you use a different libstdc++ on the RPi.

Comment: Following on from @Msalters comment, it's also possible that you're compiling for your target system using your development host's headers.  Whilst `std::shared_ptr` is a template (and thus compiled almost entirely from source) the implementation details of the `std::atomic` used in the reference count may well vary, and it may be result in different storage layout.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments! Indeed, the problems were different and incompatible versions of libstdc++ in the different build environments. Thus, I could solve the problem by converting the library to a Qt project to ensure compiling all parts with same dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the reason was different versions of libstdc++ I have on the same system for compiling a autotools project and a Qt project. However, even if I solved the problem by converting the library into an Qt project ensuring the use of the same libstdc++ for both parts, I do not understand why there are different versions on the same machine? Is this a specific feature of Qt? Mayby, anybody could explain...

Comment: If you installed Qt including QtCreator and libraries for cross-compilation, then yes it will install those libraries.